# How to get multiple avatars in only 1 request using Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I developed a method for get (doing http requests) the facebook avatars of my friends and convert each image as Sprite. If I have 5 friends i'm doing 5 requests. It worked some months ago. But now it doesn't work. I receive a 'time out' response when I try to get the second avatar.

I suppose that this problem is related to the quantity of requests that i'm doing. Maybe Facebook has a new 'flood protection'.

So, now, i'm trying to make an only one http request for obtain ALL avatars at the same time. In the official documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) I read that I should use "Batch request" but the response that i'm getting doesn't contain the information for construct each image. How can I solve it?

Background:
C++ / cocos2d-x / class network::HttpRequest

```
network::HttpRequest* req = new network::HttpRequest();
req->setUrl("https://graph.facebook.com");

vector<string> header;
header.emplace_back("User-Agent: MyApp/1.0");
header.emplace_back("Content-Type: application/json");
req->setHeaders(header);

req->setRequestData(requestBody.c_str(), requestBody.length());
req->setRequestType(network::HttpRequest::Type::POST);
network::HttpClient::getInstance()->send(req);
```

`requestBody` content:

```
{
“batch”: [
{
“method”: GET
“relative_url”: http://…url to the direct download to avatar-image
},
{
“method”: GET
“relative_url”: http://…url to the direct download to avatar-image
}
],
“access_token”: “…”
}
```

(All of the relative_url works because I tested it in a browser)
Example of data response that I'm receiving:

```
[{
“code”: 200,
“headers”: [{
“name”: “Expires”,
“value”: “Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT”
}, {
“name”: “Cache-Control”,
“value”: “private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate”
}, {
“name”: “Access-Control-Allow-Origin”,
“value”: “ "
}, {
“name”: “Pragma”,
“value”: “no-cache”
}, {
“name”: “Strict-Transport-Security”,
“value”: “max-age=15552000; preload”
}, {
“name”: “ETag”,
“value”: ““3f2ef278dacb9dfc1c3827404a99ad8dfedc20cd””
}, {
“name”: “Vary”,
“value”: “Accept-Encoding”
}, {
“name”: “X-App-Usage”,
“value”: “{“call_count”:10,“total_cputime”:0,“total_time”:0}”
}, {
“name”: “Content-Type”,
“value”: “text/javascript; charset=UTF-8”
}, {
“name”: “Facebook-API-Version”,
“value”: “v2.12”
}],
“body”: “{“id”:“https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic”}”
}]
```

With that response I don't have the information for construct an image-sprite. Example of the responseData that I need for construct 1 sprite-image: \377\330\377\340

Comment: `http://…url to the direct download to avatar-image` – trying to request those in a batch request makes rather little sense to begin with, I think. Batch requests are not made to perform HTTP “downloads” of such resources. (Plus those are not _relative_ URLs either.)

Comment: Then? What's the solution?

Comment: To request the images individually … The response to a batch request will be a JSON data structure anyway, that is not going to contain binary image data, but only CDN image URLs. _“Example of the responseData that I need for construct 1 sprite-image: \377\330\377\340”_ - don’t understand what you mean by that.

Comment: If I do a GET request to one relative_url, the server responses me the binary image for construct the sprite. The problem of doing 1 by 1 is that Facebook doesn't like it (it's consider flood). So, I want to request ALL binary-images in only 1 request. The response should have ALL binaries for each image. How can I do that?

Comment: You don’t, because you can’t. This is not a use case for batch requests, they were not made for that. There is no way to get the actual image data for multiple profile pictures in one request.

Comment: Are you sure that I can't ? If yes, then, what's the solution? Currently, I can construct the first avatar ok, but in the second request I receive a "timed out" response. I also tested delaying each request but it didn't work.

Comment: @misorude you're not giving me the solution. Please, help.